# Alpine Docker: hostname service wont start: "sethostname: Operation not permitted"

Tags: docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux, hostname

I created a simple image based on Alpine which uses openrc. When trying to start the hostname (or netowrking) service with `service start hostname`, the following error occurs:

```
 * Setting hostname ...
hostname: sethostname: Operation not permitted                                                                                                                                                                                                                          [ !! ]
 * ERROR: hostname failed to start
```

The hostname of the container is set and is correct inside `/etc/hostname`

Found this post, however I'd prefer not to add SYS_ADMIN cap: [Alpine Linux docker set hostname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45462303/alpine-linux-docker-set-hostname)

What is needed to resolve the problem?

Snippet from my Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine

VOLUME /sys/fs/cgroup

RUN apk add gitea openrc postgresql15

COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

RUN openrc &&\
    touch /run/openrc/softlevel &&\
    chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

CMD ["/bin/sh","/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: `What is needed to resolve the problem?` Not setting hostname. Not doing it is needed to resolve the problem.

Comment: I'd like to use gitea as a service which depends on the networking service, which needs the hostname service

Comment: So run gitea, like `gitea`, not `service`. Overall, do not run openrc.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to set up a virtual machine and not necessarily a container.  A container normally runs only a single process; if you need two separate things like an application and its database, that is typically run in two separate containers.  You shouldn't need a "networking service" in a container since Docker fully manages the container network environment.

Comment: You may be also interested in supervisord . Overall, consider docker-compose.yml with separate docker containers with postgres and gitea. Jus tlike in the official docs https://docs.gitea.com/next/installation/install-with-docker#basics